# Does the Wii U use the Internet to update games?

Tags: wii-u

AFAIK the Wii doesn't have patches or updates of any kind for its games. Is this still true for Wii U?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Wii U does in fact patch games if necessary, the Wii did too.

The thing about the Wii was that - just like with the 3DS - users would need to download patches manually, as if they were DLCs. One such patch was released for [*The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword*](http://zeldawiki.org/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Skyward_Sword_Save_Data_Update_Channel).

The Wii U can patch games automatically. One such example would be [*Pikmin 3*](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2013/07/theres_a_day_one_pikmin_3_update_waiting_for_you).

Comment: My WiiU also had to perform a lengthy system update before I could even use the eShop.